# change request value on null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel and I want to change one requests value on null but I can not do that

```
  if($request->productCat_id == "null"){
    $request->productCat_id = null;
  }
```

the $request->all() gives me this :

```
array:26 [▼
  "title" => null
  "type" => "product"
  "description" => null
  "productCat_id" => "null"
  "price" => null
  "off_price" => null
  "amount" => null
  "weight" => null
  "color_1" => "#000000"
  "color_2" => "#a89d8e"
  "color_3" => "#a89d8e"
  "color_4" => "#a89d8e"
  "color_5" => "#a89d8e"
  "feature_1" => null
  "feature_2" => null
  "feature_3" => null
  "feature_4" => null
  "feature_5" => null
  "feature_6" => null
  "feature_7" => null
  "feature_8" => null
  "feature_9" => null
  "feature_10" => null
  "tags" => null
  "action" => "justSave"
]
```

you can see the productCat_id is null as a string

but when I use dd($request->productCat_id) it gives me :

```
null
```

it is so strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge data into the request:

```
$request->merge(['productCat_id' => null]);
```

When you are setting a property on the request, `$request->productCat_id = ...;`, that is not the input source that it is updating. It is actually setting a property on the object. When you try to access that property `$request->productCat_id` you are accessing the property you had set on the object, not data from the input source, because a property does exist and it does not hit the magic method `__get` which would pull from the input source.